# Should I expect to have exactly same match everytime I run the match with greedy algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, local, matching, greedy

I'm using greedy algorithm or local algorithm to match propensity score in two groups. I will end up with same number of matches every time but sometimes it doesn't match exactly same with last time. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Greedy" doesn't necessarily mean "deterministic," in particular if you have two choices with equal weight/value then it may be possible to first select one choice during one algorithm execution and to first select the other choice on another algorithm execution.

Comment: But doesn't greedy algorithm always select the first that meets the selection criteria?

Comment: the order is not changing

Comment: @monkey In that case something is probably going awry with your algorithm - are there any other sources of non-determinism that you can eliminate?

Comment: @monkey: are you certain? the choice of your algo may be deterministic, but the order of data upon which the algo makes it choices may change. eg. perl doesn't guarantee the same element order in subsequent iterations over hash map keys, not even in the same process and even when the hash map is not altered in between.

Comment: Some objects have hash codes reflecting their address. This could make iterations over hash tables vary with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization